# NPOCO Fetch - Object must implement IConvertible

Tags: c#, sql-server, npoco

This is my first attempt to use NPOCO and I'm trying to read a MS SQLEXPRESS database

NPOCO "2.2.49" from NuGet,
SQLEXPRESS 2008 R2,
VS 2013, .NET 4.5

Connectionstring is

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="TrackTime.Properties.Settings.connectionDB" connectionString="Data Source=ame-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=TrackTime;Integrated Security=True"
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

The code is

```
db = new Database("TrackTime.Properties.Settings.connectionDB");
var tracks = db.Fetch<trackdatum>();
// List<trackdatum> tracks = db.Fetch<trackdatum>();

trackdatum class
        using NPoco;
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    namespace TrackTime
    {
        [TableName("trackdata")]
        [PrimaryKey("trackdata_id")]
        [ExplicitColumns]
        public partial class trackdatum
        {
            [Column]
            public string trackdata_customer { get; set; }

            [Column]
            public DateTime trackdata_date { get; set; }

            [Column]
            public DateTime trackdata_end { get; set; }

            [Column]
            public int trackdata_id { get; set; }

            [Column]
            public string trackdata_note { get; set; }

            [Column]
            public string trackdata_project { get; set; }

            [Column]
            public DateTime trackdata_start { get; set; }

            [Column]
            public string trackdata_task { get; set; }

            [Column]
            public TimeSpan trackdata_worked { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

On this line

```
var tracks = db.Fetch<trackdatum>();
```

(I have tried the commented line also with the same result.)

I get this exception

```
System.InvalidCastException was unhandled
HResult=-2147467262
Message=Object must implement IConvertible.
Source=mscorlib
StackTrace:
   at System.Convert.ChangeType(Object value, Type conversionType, IFormatProvider provider)
   at NPoco.PocoData.<>c__DisplayClass19.<GetConverter>b__14(Object src)
   at poco_factory_0(IDataReader , trackdatum )
   at NPoco.Database.<Query>d__7`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at NPoco.Database.Fetch[T](Sql sql)
   at NPoco.Database.Fetch[T](String sql, Object[] args)
   at NPoco.Database.Fetch[T]()
```

SNIP ...

Why? and how do I fix it?

// Anders

Answer (score 5):

You've probably solved it already but the problem may be that you're fetching a column with datatype `TIME` from the database and try to map it to a property with datatype `DATETIME` in your C# class. If so, change the datatype to `TIMESPAN` in the C# code and it should work I believe.

Answer (score 4):

Depends on your stack trace it needs that your `POCO` properties must implement `IConvertible` from which the `TimeSpan` doesn't.

Comment: Aha! Any suggestions, links or .., on how I implement IConvertible for a TimeStamp?

Comment: it has data type: time(7)

Comment: I had this same Iconvertible error and it was because of a database column having a type of uniqueidenitifer in SQL Server. It could not map this to a string in C# using npoco. I fixed this changing the C# type to Guid